# Gap between uiviews when view.addSubview - Swift

Tags: ios, swift3, subview

I have a SegmentControl (SC) and a UIView (U1) that are aligned next to each other. When I add another UIView (U2) in U1 there's a gap between U2's top and U1's top.

```
placeholderView.addSubview(childViewController.view)

childViewController.view.bounds = placeholderView.bounds
childViewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

The gap is pretty clear in this pic:
https://uploadpie.com/lx4b84

I've tried so much but the gap won't disappear. Someone's got an idea?

Comment: Try to set the frame of childViewController.view to placeholderView.bounds.

Comment: What an easy and elegant solution... THANK YOU!